# Can StyleCop provide a warning if someone does a new on an object that should be dependency injected?

Tags: dependency-injection, stylecop

We're considering, as a company, adopting StyleCop to enforce C# style guidelines.

One problem we occasionally see is that developers will new up an object of a class that really should have been injected as an interface.

Our standard practice is that classes with behavior should be wrapped by interfaces and should be injected, so that they can be mocked in unit tests.

And that the only classes that should ever be constructed with new, outside the container configuration, are plain, data-only classes.

My question is whether this is something that StyleCop's rules can catch for us - catching instances of calling new on a class that has methods.

Comment: "One problem we occasionally see is that developers will new up an object of a class that really should have been injected as an interface." Might the source of the problem be a lack of training, mentoring, and missing code reviews?

Comment: That said, I can't imagine that there are rules built-in for this, but it is probably possible to build a custom rule for this. But I'm really wondering whether this is worth spending your time on.

Comment: We've been catching this in code review, and it only happens a few times with new hires.